# Inserting a text into a specific line

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to create a function which inserts texts between lines according to the user input. The user has to specify the line number and the index in order to insert his line.

Currently, I have managed to insert the text before the line, but I can't insert it into the line "index". 
Does anyone know how to insert according to the index number?
PS. I am still starter at C programming. I know there are too many times that the file is opened and closed!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void inserttext(void);

main ()
{
    inserttext();
}    

void inserttext(void)
{
    FILE *file1,*file2;
    char *f = malloc(sizeof(char)), *t = malloc(sizeof(char));
    int l,i,r,y,n,index,nl=0;

    printf("Enter a text file name: ");
    scanf("%s",f);

    if (access(f,F_OK)!=-1)//if the text file exists
    {
        file1=fopen(f, "r+");
        file2=fopen("f2.txt", "w+");
        printf("\nThe file before editing:\n\n");
        while((n=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)// to show the contents of the file before the edit
        {
            putchar(n);
        }
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);

        if(access(f,W_OK)!=-1)//if the file has the write permission
        {
            file1=fopen(f, "r+");
            file2=fopen("f2.txt", "w+");

            printf("\n\nPlease enter your text: \n");
            scanf(" %[^\n]s ",t);

            printf("Specify the line number where you want to insert: ");
            scanf("%d", &l);

            printf("\nindex:\n");
            scanf("%d", &index);

            while((r=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)//copying file1 contents into file2 contents
            {
                fputc(r,file2);
                if(r == '\n' && ++nl == l){
                    fprintf(file2, "%s ", t);//adding the inserted text
                }
            }
            fclose(file1);
            fclose(file2);

            file1=fopen(f, "w+");
            file2=fopen("f2.txt", "r");
            while((y=fgetc(file2))!=EOF){
                    fputc(y,file1);
            }
            fclose(file2);
            fclose(file1);
            remove("f2.txt");

            file1=fopen(f, "r");
            printf("\n");
            while((i=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)//showing the result after inserting
            {
                putchar(i);
            }
            fclose(file1);
            free(f);
            free(t);
            }
            else{
            printf("\n%s text file does not have the Write Permission!", f);
            free(f);
            free(t);
            return;
                }
            }else{
                printf("file doesn't exits!\n");
            }
}
```

Comment: `char *f = malloc(sizeof(char))` is this correct?

Comment: you only read the index, but don't check nor make a good use of it. what index do you mean anyway? column number?

Comment: @Subinoy: good catch. he might be lucky not to write in invalid memory (but probably overwrite some valid memory).

Comment: @LeleDumbo yeah, the column number. I only read the index, but I need to make use of it in the column.

Comment: @Subinoy yeah, it works for me. I sometimes use `char *f = malloc(sizeof(*f))` too.

Comment: Learning new :), i never tried this @OsamahAl-Ghammari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `ftell()` and `fseek()` to save the file position at the start of the selected line, read the length of the line and return to the start of the line.
The user is prompted to input an index into the line less than the line length.
I did get a segmentation fault with the original malloc's for *t and *f. I tried some longer inputs, so this allocates 100 characters to each pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void inserttext(void);

int main ()
{
    inserttext();
    return 0;
}

void inserttext(void)
{
    FILE *file1,*file2;
    char *f = malloc(100), *t = malloc(100);
    int l,i,r,y,n,index,nl=0;
    int linelength = 0;;
    long offset = 0;

    printf("Enter a text file name: ");
    scanf("%99s",f);

    if (access(f,F_OK)!=-1)//if the text file exists
    {
        file1=fopen(f, "r+");
        file2=fopen("f2.txt", "w+");
        printf("\nThe file before editing:\n\n");
        while((n=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)// to show the contents of the file before the edit
        {
            putchar(n);
        }
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);

        if(access(f,W_OK)!=-1)//if the file has the write permission
        {
            file1=fopen(f, "r+");
            file2=fopen("f2.txt", "w+");

            printf("\n\nPlease enter your text: \n");
            scanf(" %99[^\n]",t);

            printf("Specify the line number where you want to insert: ");
            scanf("%d", &l);

            while((r=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)//copying file1 contents into file2 contents
            {
                fputc(r,file2);
                if(r == '\n' && ++nl == l){
                    offset = ftell ( file1);//save location in file
                    while ( ( r = fgetc ( file1)) != '\n' && r != EOF) {
                        linelength++;//count characters in line
                    }
                    fseek ( file1, offset, SEEK_SET);//seek  back to start of line
                    //get index where to insert text
                    do {
                        printf("\nindex(less than %d):\n", linelength);
                        if ( ( scanf("%d", &index)) != 1) {
                            scanf ( "%*[^\n]");//input not an integer. clear buffer
                            index = linelength;
                        }
                    } while ( index >= linelength || index < 0);

                    while ( index) {
                        r = fgetc ( file1);
                        fputc(r,file2);
                        index--;
                    }
                    fprintf(file2, "%s ", t);//adding the inserted text
                }
            }
            printf("\nDONE:\n");
            fclose(file1);
            fclose(file2);

            file1=fopen(f, "w+");
            file2=fopen("f2.txt", "r");
            while((y=fgetc(file2))!=EOF){
                    fputc(y,file1);
            }
            fclose(file2);
            fclose(file1);
            remove("f2.txt");

            file1=fopen(f, "r");
            printf("\n");
            while((i=fgetc(file1))!=EOF)//showing the result after inserting
            {
                putchar(i);
            }
            fclose(file1);
            free(f);
            free(t);
        }
        else{
            printf("\n%s text file does not have the Write Permission!", f);
            free(f);
            free(t);
            return;
        }
    }else{
        printf("file doesn't exits!\n");
    }
}
```